# Asynchronous functions in an else block

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to the whole asynchronous topic, I don't even know, if I identified the issue right. Basically I have a function with several else if conditions, which handels a buttonClick

```
function handleButtonClick () {
 if(x) { alert(x) }
 else if(y) { alert(y) }
 else if(z) { alert(z) }
 else {
  ...some code
 }
}
```

What I am fighting with is the else block. There I want first run the function:

```
function replaceButtons() {
 document.getElementById('btn-submit').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('btn-loading').style.display = 'block';
}
```

After this is done the whole bunch of actions should run, like generate pdf, send server request, check server response. Below a short example of how it looks, which doesn't represent the whole code I have

```
else {
  replaceButtons()
  let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210], true);
  pdf.text(10, 280, 'Foo');
  pdf.text(10, 285, 'Bar');

  let blob = pdf.output('blob');
  const formData = new FormData();   
  formData.append('file', blob);
  $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/test',
    {
       method: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,       
     });
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/test', { method: "POST" })
   .then(function(response) { alert('Success')}
}
```

Obviously it takes some time for it to run. That is why I want my button to be switched to a 'loading' button. For now `replaceButtons()` runs synchronously with the whole else-block, so that the required effect can only be seen after server response. So, I've researched about promises and tried this out.

```
const loader = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 resolve(replaceButtons());
});
      
loader.then(function() {
 let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210], true); 
 .......

 fetch('http://localhost:8080/test', { method: "POST" })
  .then(function(response) { alert('Success')}
}
```

But still the `replaceButtons()` only appears after the response is sent from server. How to run this after another?

Comment: Why are you calling `$.ajax` and `fetch` with the same url? Can we assume you only meant to have one or the other of these

Comment: Also "so that the required effect can only be seen after server response" doesnt make a whole lot of sense. Can you be a bit clearer what the issue is, preferably using a [mcve]

Comment: Dear @Jamiec, the code works, apart from replaceButtons(), fetch and $.ajax are not the issues I am having. I want buttons be switched before the whole pdf generating, server requests, etc. For now, buttons are switched after server response comes, so after the whole else block is executed

Comment: Aaah right, thats the fault of the pdf library - if that doesnt support async operation theres not much you can do except push it to a web worker. Javascript is single threaded and if the pdf library doesnt yield control the UI cant update

Comment: let me see if I understood it right: after the user clicks the button, you want it to change it to a loading state, generate the pdf, once it's ready, set it back to the original state (so it can be clicked again)?

Comment: @germanio exactly.

Comment: are you using any framework/library to modify the DOM? (like Vue.js, React, Angular)

Comment: Also, I would suggest to use await/async to handle promises, because it makes the code to look like it's executing sequentially (easier to follow). For instance: - `replaceButtons();`, then `const resp= await $.ajax(...);`, then do something with the response... and finally call a `restoreButtons();` that does the opposite to `replaceButtons()`. Give it a try and let us know please

Comment: No, just vanilla js and html

Comment: "*the replaceButtons() only appears after the response is sent from server*" - no, they appear when the PDF has been generated and the ajax and fetch requests have been sent. It does not wait for the server response.